# Project access denied using Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven-2

I have a Maven project (made of 5 subprojects) I cloned from a Git Repository.

When I compile (mvn clean install) them I get no errors, but, when I import them in Eclipse and try to Right Click > Maven > Update Project on the main one, I get error messages with (Access Denied) on every subproject (not on the main, which, btw is the parent folder with the subprojects' folders in it).

I already checked the folder properties and gave full access on every directory and file for every user, I am actually modifying the files and developing the application, but I still get these error messages when I try to update the project.

Is there an obvious solution I am not seeing?

On a side note: Also my coworker is having the same issue.

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: "Updating Maven Project" has encountered a problem.
Unable to update Maven configuration.

And then another window opens listing the subprojects it can't update and saying:
(project path)/.classpath (Access is denied)

Comment: Unable to update Maven configuration
Could not write file: (project path)\.classpath.
(project path)\.classpath (Access is denied)

Comment: Is the project on a shared drive?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I had the same problem on a Windows 8 64bit. The problem was that the file `.classpath` had the hidden flag set. After I removed the hidden flag, everything was fine..

You just remove the .classpath and .project then continue the operations.

Comment: Same with Windows 7 64 bit. And actually i'm using IntelliJ.

Comment: where i remove a .classpath

Answer (score 6):

This can be caused by:

- The project being on a network drive
- Wrong permissions of the folder or any parent folder
- A virus scanner preventing unknown executables from accessing the hard disk

To check whether it's a permission problem, create the project in the root of your hard disk and in your home directory.

To check whether it's a problem with the virus scanner, disable it.

Comment: I'm upvoting you and thanking you for your time, since this is a really good answer.
But I still have the same problem even trying disabling the virus scanner and placing the project in my root, so I'm not going to accept this one for now.

Comment: Can you edit the `.classpath` file from within Eclipse? You may have to make it visible by editing the filters applied to the "Package Explorer"

Answer (score 2):

In my(Windows 7 64 bit) case this caused by the

`.classpath` file having the security block turned on.

Just right click on `.classpath` file, select properties and unblock it.

Answer (score 0):

I fix it by un-hiding the whole folder on \.eclipse.

Select all folders, right click > Properties > Attributes - uncheck Hidden

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed by removing hidden flag from top folder of project through windows explorer.

Answer (score 0):

This can also be fixed by restarting the Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10:

`C:\Users\<user_name>\` should have `.m2` and `.eclipse` folder.

If they are hidden, right click and un-hide them. 
Apply the change in sub folder and files. This should solve the problem for me.